# Contentflow: how to set fixed widths for flow non-image items

Tags: coverflow

so I'm trying to use ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) to display non-image content pulled from a database. I have each of the ContentFlow items loading database content via AJAX, however, I would like to customize it so that the items have a fixed width.

eg. I watch to display 5 items in the coverflow. I want the center/primary item to be the largest in size (about 700px by 500px)

then I would like to the adjacent items about 100px and 70px wide respectively.

From what I've seen with the code, the ContentFlow width adjusts according to the browser width.

Is there a way to fix the item widths depending on which position they're in?

thanks